# Insert max numeric value in Postgres column

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE public.products
(
    id       INTEGER NOT NULL
    article  CHARACTER VARYING(255)
    name     CHARACTER VARYING(255)
    quantity NUMERIC(10, 3)
)
```

As you can see, max value that can be inserted into `quantity` field is `9999999`. If I try to insert value like `9999999+1`, of course I receive

> Numeric value out of range: 7 ERROR:  numeric field overflow

Is there any way to track on `INSERT`/`UPDATE` that value of `quantity` exceeds `9999999` and instead of this value `insert`/`update` column with `9999999`?

Of course `NUMERIC(10, 3)` can be `NUMERIC(10, 2)` or `NUMERIC(5, 2)` and whatever, so the maximum value should **not be hardcoded** in query text.

In pseudocode it is something like

```
UPDATE table SET quantity = IF value > 9999999 THEN 9999999 ELSE value;
```

Sure, I can perform some data checks **before** running pgsql-query, but currently this is the last solution that I can use.

Comment: The question is absolutely correct. It is constantly downvoted by resentful people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no built-in features to limit numeric values in the described manner. You can create and use a function to implement this behavior:

```
create or replace function limited_numeric(val numeric, prec int, scale int)
returns numeric language sql immutable as $$
    select least(mx, val)
    from (
        select format('%s.%s', repeat('9', prec- scale), repeat('9', scale))::numeric as mx
    ) s
$$;
```

Example usage:

```
insert into products 
values (1, 'article 1', 'name 1', limited_numeric(12345678, 10, 3))
returning *;

 id |  article  |  name  |  quantity   
----+-----------+--------+-------------
  1 | article 1 | name 1 | 9999999.999
(1 row)
```

There is no kind of constraint to automatically accomplish this. Neither you can use a trigger for this because numeric value overflow is checked before any trigger is executed.